# How do I pull and run a docker compose configuration rather than individual images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two applications - one a server and one a webapp - running in one docker container each - let's call them "foo" and "bar".

The web app is its own image (`Dockerfile-foo`) and the server app is its own image (`Dockerfile-bar`).

With a `docker-compose.yml` file, I have a single configuration (I'll call it "FooBar") that configures the two together. Including port mapping, volumes etc.

I can launch both together with `docker compose up` and stop them with `docker compose stop` from my source directory where the `Dockerfile`s and `docker-compose` file reside. That's all well and good.

With `docker compose push` (note the `compose` in this `push` command), I have pushed what I assume to be the entire config of both images. However, I do not seem to see anything corresponding to the "composition", just the two individual images, in the hub.

Now, if I want to run the two applications together in the same configuration, on another machine, what should I `docker compose pull` from the hub? There's nothing that corresponds to "FooBar" there, and I would really like to not duplicate port mapping and volume definitions. This machine does not have any source on it, just docker (signed in with the same user).

Answer (score 1):

You still need a docker-compose file in order to run them even if you want to pull images from hub.

This docker-compose file should contain almost identical configuration but you can skip `build` option for service, since you suppose to pull images from the hub, instead you still need to provide an `image` key.

Here is an example:

```
version: "3"

services:
  foo:
    image: foo:latest

  bar:
    image: bar:latest
```

Comment: Thanks. I imagine I'll also have to define ports and volumes in it too?

Comment: That's correct. You can even copy the docker-compose file, just to make sure you run `docker compose pull` in order to avoid buld phase, you can also drop `build` section completely in order to avoid building to happen in any case

Comment: If your original `volumes:` overwrite the source code in the image, make sure you delete those – the target system presumably won't have the complete source tree checked out.